# Ajuda - Formulário de Cadastro

Tags: php, html, formulário, email, envio-de-email

Boa tarde!
Fiz um formulário de cadastro bem simples que envia os dados para o e-mail.
Ele estava funcionando 100% e simplesmente parou de enviar os e-mails.

Após todo o cadastro, ao clicar em " enviar " o usuário é redirecionado normalmente para a página de " cadastro concluido " mas o e-mail não é enviado.

Segue HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<div class="linha">
    <section>
        <div>

        <!--formulário de cadastro -->
        <form  style="margin: 2%;" id="cadastro" name="formCadEmpre"  method="post" action="cadastroEmpresa.php" onsubmit="return validaCampo(); return false;">

            <!--dados do representante-->
            <fieldset id="dadosrepres" class="coluna col6"> 
                <legend> Dados do Representante legal </legend>

                <!--nome-->
                <p style="margin-top: 18pt;"><label for="cNome"></label><input required="" type="text" name="tNome" id="cNome" size="20" maxlength="60" minlength="10" placeholder="Nome Completo do responsável"></p>

                <!--Email-->
                <p><label for="cEmail"></label> <input required="" type="email" name="tEmail" id="cEmail" maxlength="60" minlength="8" placeholder="E-mail do responsável"></p>

                <!--celular-->
                <p><label for="cCelular"></label> <input required="" onkeypress="mascara( this, mcel ); " type="numero" name="tCelular" id="cCelular" maxlength="15" minlength="13" placeholder=" Celular para contato ( Apenas números )"></p><br>
            </fieldset>

            <!--dados do estabelecimento-->
            <fieldset id="dadosestabel" class="coluna col6">
                <legend>Dados do Estabelecimento</legend>

                <!-- nome fantasia -->
                <p><input required="" type="text" name="tFantasia" id="cFantasia" maxlength="30" placeholder="Nome do seu Estabelecimento"></p>

                <!--CNPJ -->
                <p><input required="" onkeypress="mascara( this, cnpj );" type="text" name="tCNPJ" id="cCNPJ" maxlength="18" minlength="18" placeholder="CNPJ do seu Estabelecimento ( apenas números )" ></p>

                <!--telefone-->
                <p><input required="" type="text"  onkeypress="mascara( this, mtel );" name="tTelefone" id="cTelefone" maxlength="15" minlength="13" placeholder="Telefone do seu estabelecimento (apenas números)"></p>

                <!--Atividade da empresa-->
                <p><label for="cAtividade"></label>
                <select name="tAtividade" id="cAtividade">
                    <option>Atividade principal da empresa</option><option>Água e gás</option><option>Alimentos & Bebidas</option><option>Animais Domésticos</option><option>Artigos de Festa</option><option>Artigos Esportivos</option><option>Cama mesa e banho</option><option>Cosméticos</option><option>Decoração</option><option>Farmácia</option><option>Jardinagem</option><option>Materiais de Construção</option><option>Moda</option><option>Padaria</option><option>Peças Automobilísticas</option><option>Suplementos</option><option>Vidraçaria</option><option>Outros</option>
                </select></p>
            </fieldset>

            <!--endereço do estabelecimento-->
            <fieldset id="enderecoestabel">
                <legend>Endereço do estabelecimento</legend>

                <!--Cep-->
                <p><label for="cCep"></label>
                <input required="" type="text" onkeypress="mascara( this, mcep );" name="tCep" id="cCep" maxlength="9" minlength="9" placeholder="CEP ( apenas números )">

                <!--estado-->
                <label for="cEstado"></label>
                    <select name="tEstado" id="cEstado">
                        <optgroup label="Nordeste">
                            <option value="Alagoas">Alagoas</option><option value="Bahia">Bahia</option><option value="Ceará">Ceará</option><option value="Maranhão">Maranhão</option><option value="Paraíba">Paraíba</option><option value="Pernambuco" selected>Pernambuco</option><option value="Piauí">Piauí</option><option value="Rio Grande do Norte">Rio grande do Norte</option><option value="Sergipe">Sergipe</option>
                        </optgroup>
                    </select>
                </p>

                <!--cidade-->
                <p><label for="cCidade"></label>
                    <input required="" type="text" name="tCidade" id="cCidade" placeholder="Cidade do Estabelecimento" maxlength="40" list="cidades">
                    <datalist id="cidades">
                        </option><option value="Abreu e lima"></option><option value="Araçoiaba"></option><option value="Cabo de santo Agostinho"></option><option value="Camaragibe"></option><option value="Igarassu"></option><option value="Ilha de Itamaracá"></option><option value="Ipojuca"></option><option value="Itapissuma"></option><option value="Jaboatão dos guararapes"></option><option value="Moreno"></option><option value="Olinda"></option><option value="Paulista"></option><option value="Recife"></option><option value="São Lourenço da Mata"></option>
                    </datalist>

                <!--Bairro-->
                <label for="cBairro"></label>
                <input required="" type="text" name="tBairro" id="cBairro" maxlength="30" placeholder="Bairro do Estabelecimento"></p>

                <!--Endereço-->
                <p><label for="cEndereço"></label>
                <input required="" type="text" name="tEndereco" id="cEndereco" maxlength="60" placeholder="Endereço do estabelecimento Ex: Av. Boa viagem 321"></p>

                <!--Complemento-->
                <p><label for="cComplemento"></label>
                <input required="" type="text" name="tComplemento" id="cComplemento" maxlength="60" placeholder="Complemento Ex: bloco A numero 13"></p>
            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar dados para analise" onclick="return validar()" id="inputcadastro">
        </form>     
        </div>  
    </section>
</div>
```

**Segue PHP**

```
   include_once('connect/connectdb.php');

$para = "contato@pocshop.com.br";

$assunto = "Cadastro Parceiro";

//inserindo dados na tabela

$celular = $_POST ["tCelular"];

$email = $_POST ["tEmail"];

$nome = $_POST ["tNome"];

$fantasia = $_POST["tFantasia"];

$telefone = $_POST["tTelefone"];

$CEP = $_POST["tCep"];

$atividade = $_POST["tAtividade"];

$estado = $_POST["tEstado"];

$cidade = $_POST["tCidade"];

$bairro = $_POST["tBairro"];

$product = $_POST["tendereco"];

$complemento = $_POST["tComplemento"];

$CNPJ = $_POST["tCNPJ"];


$dbh = open_connection_database();

$sql = "SELECT idsupplier FROM supplier WHERE email= :email";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':email', $login);

$stmt->execute();

$idsuppliers = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (count($idsuppliers) >= 1) {
    echo '<script> history.go(-1); alert("Email ja cadastrado no sistema!");
</script>';

} else {
    $corpo = "<strong> Um novo cadastro foi realizado! </strong><br><br>";

    $corpo .= "<h1>Dados do Representante</h1><br><strong> Nome: </strong> $nome";

    $corpo .= "<br><strong> Celular: </strong> $celular";

    $corpo .= "<br><strong> Email: </strong> $email<br><br>";

    $corpo .= "<h1>Dados do Estabelecimento</h1><br><strong> Nome Fantasia: </strong> $fantasia";

    $corpo .= "<br><strong> CNPJ: </strong> $CNPJ";

    $corpo .= "<br><strong> Telefone: </strong> $telefone";

    $corpo .= "<br><strong> CEP: </strong> $CEP";

    $corpo .= "<br><strong> Atividade: </strong> $atividade";

    $corpo .= "<br><strong> Estado: </strong> $estado";

    $corpo .= "<br><strong> Cidade: </strong> $cidade";

    $corpo .= "<br><strong> Bairro: </strong> $bairro";

    $corpo .= "<br><strong> Endereço: </strong> $endereco";

    $corpo .= "<br><strong> Complemento: </strong> $complemento";


    $header = "Content-type: text/html; charset= utf-8\n";

    $header .= "From: $email Reply-to: $email\n";

    mail($para, $assunto, $corpo, $header);

    header("location:cadConcluido.html");
}
```

Comment: Quando parou de enviar? Depois que você subiu na nuvem?

Comment: Qual hospedagem você está usando?

Answer (score 0):

Existem algumas coisas que você pode fazer para que sua mensagem não seja bloqueada.

**Como evitar que a mensagem seja bloqueada**

- **Campo From**:
  deve ser um e-mail de seu domínio, do contrário, poderá ter problemas com o recebimento das mensagens também por conta do bloqueio de segurança dos servidores de diversos provedores;
- **Return-Path**: deve ser o mesmo e-mail especificado em From, se ele não for especificado ou for especificado um e-mail diferente, a mensagem pode não chegar no destino por conta do bloqueio de segurança dos servidores de diversos provedores;
- **Campo Reply-To**: é ideal para formulários que tem como função enviar e-mail para uma caixa postal sua (@dominio.com), pois quando se responde, o destinatário será o e-mail do visitante. Se usar o e-mail do visitante no campo From, a mensagem poderá ser barrada por conta do tópico acima.

*Obs: É importante a utilização "Return-Path" para receber o retorno das mensagens e identificar mais rapidamente as falhas no envio.*

Ou seja, no seu caso o Return-Path, pode ser a cereja do bolo que está faltando.

```
$headers .= "Return-Path: eu@seudominio.com\n";
```

Fonte: [locaweb](http://wiki.locaweb.com/pt-br/Como_enviar_e-mails_com_a_fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_mail()_do_PHP)

Além disso, dependendo da sua hospedagem/servidor, poderá haver outros fatores como:

- função `mail` necessita configuração na autenticação via htaccess.
- Limite de envios da sua hospedagem.
- Outras configurações no `header` que sua hospedagem exige.

Porém, eu aconselho você a usar o [phpMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), que na minha opinião, é mais fácil de usar e você terá 100% de envio. [Veja o tutorial do Thiago Belém](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/enviar-e-mails-pelo-php-usando-o-phpmailer).